# subclassing listview for referencing multiple views to one template django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Let's say in a website there is a profile page for users and it is a blog website. So every user has some blogs that they have written. So I want the profile page to be like: It will show the detailed stuffs about that user, like username, email. And also all the blogs they have written should be listed there. Now I have two views here, one for the detailed profile stuffs and another is for listing blogs written by the user.

```
#view for detailed profile stuffs
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User

#view for listing blogs written by user
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post 
    paginate_by = 5
```

Also the Post model is like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
```

Now as you can see one view inherits from ListView and another inherits from DetailView.
In order to use these two views to render what I am wanting, I can't pass two views to one template. So I need to subclass one of them.Now, as I want to keep pagination, I should subclass UserPostListView and maybe override get_context_data(). So how can I do this? I can't find any satisfactory answer. Also I am very new to django.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by subclassing the ListView like this:

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.usr = get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['prof'] = self.usr.profile
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(author=self.usr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to first update the Post model - add a foreign key field to user in order to know which user has posted what. Next override get_context_data() function in ProfileDetailView and pass all the posts written by the user in the context.
Your get_context_data() cal would look something like-

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProfileDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    user = self.get_object()
    posts = Post.objects.filter(user=user)
    context.update({'posts': posts})
    return context
```

You can then render the posts for each profile on the template by-

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.title }}
    {{ post.comment }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Will pagination remain same in this case?